# Sql Server Connectivity for Windows Application over Linux

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc, sqlcmd, wine

I am a C# Programmer, I am wanted to run windows forms app to Linux, 2 days i tried to run the application in Linux but now application is running with help of Wine but ms-SQL server connectivity is ending with timeout but i can connect to Linux terminal with the help of sqlcmd and it is working perfectly but in wine applications are not accepting connection can you please help me to access SqlServer to wine applications ?

Comment: You're fighting a losing battle here, in my opinion. WINE stands for "Wine Is Not an Emulator" and it isn't. The drivers that are used on Windows are different to that on Linux, which is something you're going to need to be able to connect to SQL Server. If you need an application that runs on Linux, you should be designing an application that runs on Linux.

Comment: But i can connect from linux  with this command sqlcmd -S xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -U sa -P password  -d master -Q "SELECT * from emp_Master ;"

Comment: *"this command"*? There are no commands in your question.

Comment: You are probably using in your connection string Integrated Security which is using the windows credentials of the user login to connect to the database.  So in Linux you have to use same credentials.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi

Comment: @user1790151 yes, because `sqlcmd` is available on Linux, as part of the `mssql-tools` apt package (on Ubuntu). SUSE and Redhad distros have it in their own package management tool as well. For all 3 distributions Microsoft have developed a Linux based version of `sqlcmd`, it isn't the same one that's on your Windows PC, and you aren't use WINE to use `sqlcmd`.

Comment: @jdweng this is unlikely, the OP says they're getting a time-out error, not a login error.

Comment: What happens when a connection fails?  The connection is made when you perform the query.  There isn't a separate login step.

Comment: @jdweng  I am using this connection string "Data Source=192.168.1.115;Initial Catalog=Master;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=yyyyyy " in application  and i am using the same credential in sqlcmd that is working in linux terminal but in case of wine app is not working. sql server is in windows

Comment: @jdweng i am sure in the wine app connection string is failing ... but i don't know how to change it

Comment: when it is failing it will give timeout error

Comment: To be honest, I think you would be better asking on the [Wine Forums](https://forum.winehq.org/). It is unlikely the problem is the application, or Linux, but that fact that you are trying to run a **Windows** application on Linux using a tool that changes it's API calls. maybe someone there knows what additional tools are needed on the host for WINE to be able to make the appropriate API calls to OBDC (or what ever driver you are using). otherwise, my statement stands: Stop trying to use an application disigned for Windows on Linux and use an Application designed for Linux.

Comment: Windows will not allow a remote PC to connect unless it is in the same group.  "See How to Grant "Allow log on locally" Permissions to Domain User Accounts" at following msdn page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/specify-credential-and-connection-information-for-report-data-sources?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Let me try thanks Larnu and  jdweng

Comment: What do you mean "in the same group" @jdweng ? I connect to SQL Servers in different domains all the time. That link is for Reporting Services, not the data engine.

Comment: hi i am not getting any log in server while connecting through wine application but i am trying to connect with Linux terminal it is logging

Comment: The data engine and report server user credentials are the same.  If you are using a corporate network Group Policies allow the connections in different domains.  You are using Linux not windows so the credentials are handed different.  The IP address for linux is not the same and windows on the same machine.

Comment: i changed wine version to 4.0 now it is logging but i am getting error  "connection successfully established with the server,but the error occurred during the login process (provider:ssl provider ,error 0-ssl provider"

Comment: ** thanks guys **  .... it is solved by updating latest version of wine